# Drywall bad joints rough edges

Tags: drywall

My husband kept cutting off the beveled edges to make easier measurements. I suggested only cutting one edge where possible. Also he was cutting the off side (brown) and leaving roygh paper edges. I also suggested cutting good side.  Maybe I should've been a little more forceful with my suggestions in the first place. Can two rough edges be joined without an obvious bump under mud?

Comment: Yes, you should have been a little more forceful with your suggestions. But rough edges can be joined with some extra effort and spreading the joint out over a larger surface of the wall to minimize the bump. Those beveled edges do make it much easier to produce a clean joint without a bump.

Comment: This is where watching some utube videos could have been helpful. Now it will take some time and a bit more mud to make a wider joint maybe up to a foot (over several layers lightly sanded until the bumps are unnoticeable This can be very tough if the room has bright lighting. That's when a heavy texture and a knockdown or stomp really help.

Comment: Top-quality tapers create joints a foot wide or more *regardless*.

Comment: Also agree with isherwood about joint size.  The drywall almost always goes up unevenly by its very nature.  Making WIDE joints with mud creates a shallow enough rise and fall to fool the eye and make it look flat.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, but it depends on the skill of the taper. (Some drywall hangers only cut one side of the sheet and literally break the other paper face with a violent snap.) Slightly ragged cuts are not a concern, as they'll be moistened when joint compound is applied and flattened when paper tape is pressed on.

If you're truly concerned about certain areas, take a utility knife with a new blade and slide it along the joint at a 45 degree angle, shaving off the edge of the paper along the cut.

Comment: Yes like isherwood said - ragged cuts are not a concern.  They're common, in fact.  That said, totally agree - hubby should cut ONE edge of the drywall when possible and cut the GOOD side first.

Comment: I hate to argue, but cutting the back side first, making the snap, then cutting the front can result in a straighter cut. The snap tends to straighten wobbles and slips in the original cut.

Comment: If making a snap, agreed - but making that snap isn't actually as easy as it looks and a lot of non-pro drywallers just do 2 cuts.  That 2nd cut, when the drywall is bent, ends up with ragged cuts and in THAT case I think cut front first is alwayy better.